# ListActivity view.setSelected(true) not registered if called by an onItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listactivity

The following happens on Android 2.2:

I have a ListActivity where a single item can be selected. I register 1)an onClickItemListener and 
2)an onItemLongClick listener

for the ListActivity's ListView. On itemClick I just set the list item being clicked as selected. On itemLongClick, I want to do the same thing and additional steps. My problem is, calling view.setSelected(true) from the onItemLongClickListener does not work - the item in the ListView does not get selected. This happens even when the exact same method is called from these two different listeners! See code below:

```
    /*
     * Set the onClickListeners for the ListView items.
     */
    this.listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            itemClick(view, position);
        }
    });
    this.listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            itemClick(view, position);
            return true;
        }
    });

    /*
     * Basic procedure when the user clicks
     * an item in the list.
     */
    private void itemClick(View view, int position) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        selectedPosition = position;
        selectedView = view;
    }
```

Here the onItemLongClickListeners returns true to prevent the click bubbling up to the onClickListener. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Turns out

```
view.setSelected(true);
```

never was working out the way I thought it was. The standard functionality of the ListActivity was selecting the item for me in the above code all the time and calling view.setSelected() never actually selected the item in the ListView. Replacing the method as follows solves my problem:

```
    /*
     * Basic procedure when the user clicks
     * an item in the list.
     */
    private void itemClick(View view, int position) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        selectedPosition = position;
        selectedView = view;
    }
```

Thanks for Jimbo for helpful clarifying questions!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when after calling "view.setSelected"? Are you expecting the item in the list to be highlighted?

Comment: I expect the radio button next to the item in the ListView to turn green to indicate to the user it has been selected. This happens now for onItemClick but not for onItemLongClick.

Comment: If you debug the itemClick(...) method while performing a long click, then if you inspect the view argument thats passed into the method is it the view object that you expect? i.e. is it a RadioButton?

Comment: Thanks for making me in a different way! My mistake was calling a wrong method all the time. I modified my question to include the answer. :)

Comment: @zenperttu, you should answer your own question. Nothing wrong to answer own questions :)